# Using BIOS functions through C++

Tags: c++, bios

I'm searching for information about managing BIOS settings through C++.
I am unfamiliar with low level programming. I tried to make a research, but my lack of knowledge in low level programming terminology terminated my progress.

I need to draw pixels on the screen, change to text mode or video mode and so on. Is it possible to do it with a C++ program?

Can someone give me some information which can guide me through the process?

Comment: This appears to be too broad because a correct answer could fill a book.

Comment: So there is no simple way in which i can set the screen color to red and write a sentence in the center, using BIOS functions?

Comment: What is the platform? What will start the program execution?

Comment: @AlexanderDemerdzhiev I think you would be better off asking how to do specifically what you want to do rather than asking for general advice ("and so on"). Although I am still tempted to downvote as "does not show any research effort"

Comment: Ok, sorry for not being concrete. I need to set the color of the screen, write text in text mode and edit it's color, draw a single pixel with a certain color somewhere on the colored screen and draw a frame with thickness of one pixel next to the screen borders.

Comment: @AlexanderDemerdzhiev edit your question with that information along with what research you have done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You question in fact has many subquestion :

- do you need some kind of a boot loader ? definitively no
- can you do that with standard portable C++  ? obviously no(*)
- can you do that from a C++ program ? yes
- what are the BIOS functions to change video mode ... [BIOS interrupt call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_interrupt_call) on wikipedia will give you the answer or at least an entry point
- how to call that from a C++ program ? `_asm` keyword is your friend. It you use Windows and a MS compiler, [_asm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/45yd4tzz.aspx) page on MSDN will give you examples.

It will look like :

```
_asm {
    mov ah, sub_function
    mov al, parameter
    int bios_function
}
```

(*) standard portable C++ is independant of platform and implementation. As soon as you use BIOS call you are tight to a platform.

Comment: Thank you. This is really helpful information.
It turns out that what i need are BIOS interruptions and knowledge how to access true memory.